# How to set bounds when minimizing using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have some `data` in a numpy array.

I would like to scale the data using a linear function according to the following rules:

1. The mean is as close to 65 as possible
2. The smallest value is at least 50

For my first attempt I made a scoring function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def score(x):
    return abs(np.mean(x[0]*data+x[1]) - 65) + abs(x[0]*np.min(data)+x[1] - 50)
```

I have added on `abs(x[0]*np.min(data)+x[1] - 50)` as a vain attempt to get it to satisfy rule 2.

I then tried:

```
x0 = [0.85,0]
res = minimize(score,x0)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print res
```

This gives:

```
fun: 4.8516444911893615
hess_inv: array([[ 0.0047, -0.1532],
       [-0.1532,  5.2375]])
      jac: array([-50.9628,  -2.    ])
message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 580
      nit: 2
     njev: 142
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([0.7408, 1.4407])
```

In other words the optimization failed.

I would also like to set bounds for the coefficients, e.g. `bounds = [(0.7,1.3),(-5,5)]`.

My question is, what is the correct way to run the optimization with the boundary condition that the scaled smallest value is at least 50? Also, how can I make it so that the optimization runs without failure?

Comment: Look at minimize' support for constraints in the tutorial! I don't get your scoring-approach. It looks broken due to having two components and due to being non-smooth. Take the first one, replace abs with a square or l2-norm, and add the missing constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

data = np.array([ 59. ,  59.5,  61. ,  61.5,  62.5,  63. ,  63. ,  65.5,  66.5,
    67. ,  68. ,  69. ,  69.5,  70.5,  70.5,  70.5,  71. ,  72. ,
    72. ,  73.5,  73.5,  74. ,  75. ,  75.5,  78. ,  79. ,  79. ,
    79. ,  79.5,  80.5,  80.5,  80.5,  80.5,  80.5,  82.5,  82.5,
    82.5,  83. ,  83. ,  83. ,  83. ,  83. ,  83.5,  83.5,  84. ,
    84.5,  84.5,  84.5,  86. ,  86. ,  86. ,  86.5,  86.5,  87.5,
    88. ,  88. ,  88.5,  89. ,  90. ,  90.5,  90.5,  90.5,  91. ,
    91.5,  91.5,  92. ,  92. ,  93. ,  93. ,  93. ,  93.5,  93.5,
    94. ,  94. ,  94. ,  94. ,  94. ,  94. ,  94.5,  94.5,  94.5,
    94.5,  95.5,  95.5,  95.5,  95.5,  95.5,  95.5,  96. ,  96. ,
    96. ,  96.5,  96.5,  96.5,  98. ,  98. ,  98. ,  98. ,  98. ,
    98. ,  98. ,  98. ,  98.5,  98.5,  98.5,  98.5,  98.5, 100. ,
   100. , 100. , 100. ])

def scale(data, coeffs):
    m,b = coeffs
    return (m * data) + b

def score(coeffs):
    scaled = scale(data, coeffs)
    # Penalty components
    p_1 = abs(np.mean(scaled) - 65)
    p_2 = max(0, (50 - np.min(scaled)))
    return p_1 + p_2

res = minimize(score, (0.85, 0.0), method = 'Powell')
#np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
print(res)

post = scale(data, res.x)

print(np.mean(post))
print(np.min(post))
print(score(res.x))
```

Outputs:

```
   direc: array([[ -3.05475495e-02,   2.62047576e+00],
       [  7.54828106e-07,  -6.47892698e-05]])
     fun: 1.4210854715202004e-14
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 360
     nit: 8
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([  0.55914442,  17.02691959])
```

```
print(np.mean(post))  # 65.0
print(np.min(post))   # 50.0164406291
print(score(res.x))   # 1.42108547152e-14
```

A few things:

- I added a `scale` helper function to clean up the code a bit, since I use it in the `score` function as well as at the end to show the scaled data.
- The `score` function was fixed and broken out into two separate penalties (one for each requirement) for clarity.  It computes the scaled vector once (and calls it `scaled`), then computes the penalty components.
- Note: This score function has an odd non-smooth area around min(data) = 50 because of the `max` call.  This may cause issues with some optimization methods.
- I used the Powell algorithm because I had used it before and it worked in a similar problem with using a min/max operator.  Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell%27s_method):

  > The method is useful for calculating the local minimum of a continuous but complex function, especially one without an underlying mathematical definition, because it is not necessary to take derivatives

  Someone more familiar with the optimization methods may be able to suggest a better alternative.
- (Edit) Lastly, with respect to your question about boundary conditions.  Usually, when we talk about boundary conditions we're talking about the boundary of the independent variable, the vector we're optimizing (here, elements of `coeffs` or `x`) -- for example, "x[0] must be less than 0", or "x[1] must be between 0 and 1" -- not what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this! I am really sorry but I didn't specify that I would also like to set bounds for the coefficients. E.g. `bounds = [(0.7,1.3),(-5,5)]`

Comment: The secret seems to be just to try all the different Methods one after another until one works.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm understanding you wrong, but just scaling the data according to those 2 rules is straight forward linear algebra:

```
e = np.mean(data)
m = e - np.min(data)

data * (65-50)/m + (65 - e*(65-50)/m)
# i.e. (data-e) * (65-50)/m + 65
```

This has exactly mean 65 and minimum 50.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't fully specify the question. I am looking for a general optimization approach as I will eventually specify bounds on the two coefficient. For example that the first is between 0.7 and 1.3 and the second is between -5 and 5.